# Python unittest - setUpClass() is giving me trouble - why can't I inherit like this?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have unittest code like the following:

```
import unittest

class MyUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpClass(self):
        do_something_expensive_for_all_sets_of_tests()

class MyFirstSetOfTests(MyUnitTest):
    def setUpClass(self):
        super(MyFirstSetOfTests, self).setUpClass()
        do_something_expensive_for_just_these_first_tests()

    def test_one(self):
        ...

    def test_two(self):
        ...

class MySecondSetOfTests(MyUnitTest):
    def setUpClass(self):
        super(MySecondSetOfTests, self).setUpClass()
        do_something_expensive_for_just_these_second_tests()

    def test_one(self):
        ...

    def test_two(self):
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error like this:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.MyFirstSetOfTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: unbound method setUpClass() must be called with MyFirstSetOfTests instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`setUpClass` *must* be a class method. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass):

> A class method called before tests in an individual class run. `setUpClass` is called with the class as the only argument and must be decorated as a `classmethod()`:
>
> ```
> @classmethod
> def setUpClass(cls):
>     ...
> ```
>
> See [Class and Module Fixtures](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) for more details.

Your version is missing the [`@classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class MyUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        do_something_expensive_for_all_sets_of_tests()

class MyFirstSetOfTests(MyUnitTest):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(MyFirstSetOfTests, cls).setUpClass()
        do_something_expensive_for_just_these_first_tests()
```

The error is thrown because `MyFirstSetOfTests.setUpClass()` is called on the *class*, not on an instance, but you didn't mark your method as a `classmethod` and thus it was not passed in the automatic `self` argument. In the above updated code I used `cls` instead, to reflect that the name references the class object.